# Contact form 7 changes showing after login only in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

URL of the issue - https://www.koruux.com/proof-of-concept/

I made the changes in contact form 7. Previously there were 10 fields. My client asked me to reduce it to 6. I removed unwanted fields. Its working successfully.

The problem is, if user see the page without login, it is not able to see the reduced form fields. He is able to see previous form with 10 fields.

And if user log in, he can see the changes means he can see updated form with just 6 fields.

The same thing is happening with some of blogs. We can see them when we are logged in. When we are logged out, we cant see them.

There is only one cache plugin used - **WP Fastest Cache**

We are using wp-engine.

I even tried to run it on kproxy but same thing is happening. We see all the fields without login.

Comment: im seeing only 6 fields, its a cache problem, try in some other system

Comment: are you sure.. Any idea why this is happening.. even kproxy showed 10 fields..

Comment: try deactivating wp fastest cache and try purge cache from wp-engine

Comment: Actually. I did the same. I checked instantly after deactivating plugin. So I might not be able to see the changes. But as I was typing issue here, it might have taken effect.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing only 6 fields, it's purely cache problem.

> 1. Try deactivating the all cache plugins
> 2. Purge cache from wp-engine
> 3. Try in different browser and system